# likelihood function with uniform prior

Tags: bayesian, likelihood, uniform-distribution

Assume I have a data sequence `{y1,y2,y3,...}`. The data comes from

```
y_t = 1 - gamma * t + epsilon_t
```

where `epsilon_t ~ N(0,sigma^2)`.

Suppose `gamma` is uniformly distributed, i.e.,`gamma ~ U[a,b]`. How shall I get the likelihood function `p(y|gamma)`?

Answer (score 1):

From your notation, it's obvious that $y_t|\gamma\sim\mathcal N(1-\gamma t,\sigma^2)$. If $\epsilon_t|\gamma$ are assumed to be independent, then $$L(\gamma)=p(y|\gamma)=\prod_{t=1}^n p(y_t|\gamma)=\prod_{t=1}^n \mathcal N(1-\gamma t, \sigma^2)$$

Prior distribution of $\gamma$ doesn't play any role in the likelihood.